Chain Rule different definitions
I'm confused about the connection between $ (f \circ g)' = f'(g(x))\,g'(x) $ and $df/dx = df/dg \cdot dg/dx$.
One is the derivative of a composite function and one is the derivative of a function with respect to one variable when you know the derivatives with respect to another variable and the derivative of that variable itself. Why are these the same thing (chain rule)?
Edit note: typo fixed

In the first formula you have an error, the last $g(x)$ should be $g'(x)$

Think about how an expression being a function “with respect to” some sub-expression can be interpreted as a composition of functions.

Alternatively: both expressions are a product of two terms.  Can you see how the terms relate across examples?

The second version is also describing a composite function, although the notation is a little confusing.
If you think about how this would look for an actual function like $\sin(2x)$, then your second notation for the chain rule is
$$
\frac {d(\sin(2x))}{dx} = \frac{d(\sin(2x))}{d(2x)} \frac{d(2x)}{dx} = 2\cos(2x).
$$
To make this look less confusing, we could let $g=2x$ and write
$$
\frac {d(\sin(2x))}{dx} = \frac{d(\sin(g))}{dg} \frac{dg}{dx} = 2\cos(g) = 2\cos(2x).
$$
But this $g$ is really a function of $x$, so it's the same as writing
$$
\frac d {dx} \sin(g(x)) = \cos(g(x)) g'(x) = 2\cos(2x),
$$
which is your first version of the chain rule.

An even more elemental example to grasp both the application as well as its power here would be
$$f(t) = t^3,\ \ g(x)=x+2\ \Rightarrow\ (f\circ g)(x)=f\left(g(x)\right)=\left(x+2\right)^3$$
You surely could calculate that in the classic way by doing multiplications first, i.e.
$$(f\circ g)(x) = \left(x+2\right)^3 = 1\cdot x^3\cdot 2^0 + 3\cdot x^2\cdot 2^1 + 3\cdot x^1\cdot 2^2 + 1\cdot x^0\cdot 2^3\\
= x^3 + 6x^2 + 12x + 8
$$
and thence you surely have
$$(f\circ g)'(x) = 3\cdot x^2 + 2\cdot 6x^1 + 1\cdot 12x^0 = 3x^2+12x+12
$$
But you also have
$$(f\circ g)'(x) = \left(f(g(x))\right)' = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)
$$
and hence simply
$$(f\circ g)'(x) = 3\left(g(x)\right)^2\cdot g'(x) = 3\left(x+2\right)^2\cdot 1
$$
Note, that this latter approach neither does require any a priori multiplications and furthermore already results in the compact form directly.
--- rk
